# How do I import incongruent (mismatched) CSV data with an existing table on Postgres, using pgAdmin?

Tags: database, postgresql, csv, pgadmin

Before we start, I *have* to use pgAdmin 4 (or the PSQL Tool, which is in Beta) Using a substitute is *not* an option.

On my CSV file, I have the following data:

(Please note that the column names, and values have been changed to protect the corporate sanctity of the data )

[image]

The table to which I will import to has all of those 4 columns mentioned in the CSV file, and also 20 other columns, which I do not care about, and I will leave blank.

On pgAdmin, I am entering the following settings to prepare my import:

[image]

Finally, in the Columns tab, I am selecting the columns I am interested in, leaving the other settings at default. The biggest problem I will run into is when the 20 other columns (which I'm not interested in) but are set to NOT NULL, will require default values inserted for them. How do I give instructions to handle each and every one of those other 20 columns?

I suspect this will most likely have to be done in the PSQL Tool utility which gives you an SSH-like session in pgAdmin.

[image]

Comment: 1) What version of `pgAdmin4`? 2) `psql` is hardly beta, it is the command line client that ships with Postgres . 3) Add the table definition to your question(**as text not an image**). 4) **DO NOT use images for textual data** per [Do not use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Should have added that given that the 20 other columns are `NOT NULL` you can't leave them blank unless you have  a non-null `DEFAULT` value defined for each column as part of the table definition. If that is not set then you will need to provide values in the incoming data. The import wizard is just using [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) behind the scenes, so you might want to read that. If you use `psql` you will probably end up using the client version [\copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY).